# Failing to unixodbc with pip

Tags: python-3.x, unixodbc, pypyodbc

I am trying to connect to MSSQM server from my python 3.9 application. I was able to install pyodbc but when i try to run `pipenv install unixodbc` it fails with the following error.

```
(src) root@16cb00f4b680:/workspaces/python-lambda/src# pipenv install unixodbc
Loading .env environment variables...
Installing unixodbc...
Resolving unixodbc...
Adding unixodbc to Pipfile's [packages] ...
✔ Installation Succeeded
Pipfile.lock (4afee8) out of date, updating to (f35dff)...
Locking [packages] dependencies...
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
✘ Locking Failed!
⠙ Locking...
CRITICAL:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.resolution.resolvelib.factory:Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement unixodbc (from versions: none)
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 811, in _main
[ResolutionFailure]:       resolve_packages(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 759, in resolve_packages
[ResolutionFailure]:       results, resolver = resolve(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 738, in resolve
[ResolutionFailure]:       return resolve_deps(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 1154, in resolve_deps
[ResolutionFailure]:       results, hashes, markers_lookup, resolver, skipped = actually_resolve_deps(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 953, in actually_resolve_deps
[ResolutionFailure]:       resolver.resolve()
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 700, in resolve
[ResolutionFailure]:       raise ResolutionFailure(message=str(e))
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]: Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
  You can use $ pipenv install --skip-lock to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the situation.
  Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
ERROR: No matching distribution found for unixodbc
```